# Unable to launch Viber on Gallium OS

Tags: viber

I am using Gallium OS which is a Distro that is built on ubuntu especially for Chromebooks.
The Distro is really amazing and extremely light but i am having one major issue which is quite important to me

whenever i try to run Viber i get this error

```
chrx@chrx:~$ /opt/viber/Viber
This application failed to start because it could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "xcb".

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, wayland-egl, wayland, xcb.

Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.
Aborted
```

Comment: You will want to find a Gallium OS q&a or forum. This question is off topic for Ubuntu.

Comment: I voted this as off-topic too

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on Kubuntu 14.04 LTS. Found the following article that solved the problem for me: [Viber on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit](http://www.roydoer.com/?p=16)

Had to install libqt5gui5:

```
sudo apt-get install libqt5gui5
```

and then re-install Viber.

Comment: This also fixes Viber on Debian Jessie